# PHP class method isn't working?

Tags: php, class

Okay so I'm taking my aim at practicing some OOP. If this class is a little overkill for what I am trying to accomplish, please let me know but I am just doing it for the practice. Basically I have this class for a form thats very basic, all it does is take name, email, and a comment or message from them and will upload it to the database. I know (actually don't KNOW, just am pretty sure) that it is the class's uploadMessage function. Was wondering if anyone could tell me where I'm going wrong with this. Thankyou! 
First is the message class -

```
class message{
        public $name;
        public $email;
        public $message;

        function __construct($name, $email, $message){
            $this->name    = $name;
            $this->email   = $email;
            $this->message = $message; 
        }

        public function uploadMessage(){
            if(!isset($this->name) || !isset($this->email) || !isset($this->message)){
                throw new Exception("One of the fields was incorrectly typed.");
            } else{

                $database = new DB("localhost","username","password","Personal_blog");
                $this->name    = mysqli_real_escape_string($database->_db,$this->name);
                $this->email   = mysqli_real_escape_string($database->_db,$this->email);
                $this->message = mysqli_real_escape_string($database->_db,$this->message);
                $query = "INSERT INTO messages(name,email,message) VALUES('".$this->name."', '".$this->email."', '".$this->message."')";
                $results = $database->query($query);
                if($results->affected_rows > 0){
                    return true;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

And below is the code I used to instantiate the class, and also call the method.

```
ini_set("display_errors",1);
    include_once "blog_functions.php";
    @ $name    = "eric" ;     //$_POST['name'];
    @ $email   = "email";     //$POST['email'];      USING FAKE VALUES HERE FOR TESTING
    @ $message = "message";   //$_POST['message'];



    echo "hey";

    try{
        $message = new message($name, $email, $message);
        $message->uploadMessage();
    }
```

As you can see, i WANT to take values from a form via the $_POST method, however just for some testing i put it some random variable values, and it would not work. The new DB() method is from another class that basically just extends the php mysqli library a little. And the $database->_db property of that close is actually the mysqli handler, which is what i used for the refernce in mysqli_real_escape_string.

Comment: By the way, the reason i think it is the uploadMessage() method is because when i take that out of my code, the echo "hey"; works. Otherwise i get absolutely nothing.

Comment: You may want to remove your username and password from the code sample.

Comment: You know those `@`'s really slow down your code right?

Comment: what does your DB class looks like

Comment: Check for error messages. Put your database lines in a try/catch block.

Comment: Is there a specific question? I can't see one.

Comment: The problem could be that `name` is a keyword in MySQL. Put your column names in reversed single quotes (`\``) and try again.

Comment: You should watch your naming of variables, you have 'message' as the name of your object aswell as the class member variable

Comment: General advice: you might want to lose this particular constructor -- it's perfectly feasible to have the information to populate the fields but not all at once or not in a convenient form for a constructor call. Additionally, your class has a dependency on `DB` but this is hidden inside the code -- instead it should have a constructor that accepts a `DB` instance so that this dependency is clear.

Comment: please, learn to use **prepared statements**.

Comment: Has the `DB` class been included? Are you getting any error messages? If so, can you put them here please. Can you do a `var_dump` through each part of the `uploadMessages` function and let us know which line specifically is causing you the issues?

Comment: @Lex Did not even think about that. Of course this is a practice environment but thankyou very much!

Comment: @FDL i did not know that, thanks for the advice. I've escaped the column names, and got nothing. But I ran the query by itself on a seperate page and i do believe it is only something in the query.

Comment: @teresko I had looked into prepared statements but had trouble learning how to store the results of a database query. Sorry if i upset any of you seasoned PHP developers? Some of you seem to be very upset, I'm just trying to learn. Words of advice from a rookie - don't be so belittling

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO messages(`name`,`email`,`message`) VALUES('".$this->name."', '".$this->email."', '".$this->message."')";
```